# How to set Google chrome preference using Selenium web driver?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried setting chrome pref usinf ChromeOption class using the following code snippet

```
Map<String, String> prefs = new Hashtable<String, String>();
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", "true");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("prefs", prefs);
//capabilities.setCapability("download.prompt_for_download", true);
driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new ChromeDriver(capabilities));
```

But no luck I am using latest driver version 2.35. I wanted to set prompt for download.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/source/browse/CapabilitiesAndSwitches.wiki?spec=svn.wiki.0eeb3aab6943a35834ddcd80005395bb03b33352&repo=wiki&r=0eeb3aab6943a35834ddcd80005395bb03b33352 Can this be of anyhelp?

Comment: View this answer. It might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824124/how-to-change-file-download-location-in-webdriver-while-using-chrome-driver-fire

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there can be a small issue with string version of boolean's and the actual boolean (i.e "true" vs true)

So I'd give this a test (untested):

```
Map<String, Boolean> prefs = new Hashtable<String, Boolean>();
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", true);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("prefs", prefs);
driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new ChromeDriver(capabilities));
```