# How to change default download location of chrome using java/selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to change chrome preferences using below code but I am not able to do.
I need to change download location of file in chrome using java/selenium.
I tried 2-3 code snippets as mentioned below but none of them works for me.

### Snippet-1

```
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

### Snippet-2

```
Map<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("--test-type");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

### Snippet-3

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change file download location in Webdriver while using chrome driver/firefox driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824124/how-to-change-file-download-location-in-webdriver-while-using-chrome-driver-fire)

Comment: one of the snippets of my problem is from that link only. But it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue .But below code helped me to solve problem and works fine.

Points to remember :-

1)Change the chrome driver path .

2)Change the downloadFilepath to desired location you needed .

Code :-

@Test

public void testDownload() throws Exception {

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
String downloadFilepath = "/path/to/download";
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
options.setExperimentalOptions("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("--test-type");

DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);

driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/file/C35/P10/");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("smilechart.xls")).click();
```

}

Thanks.