# Finding downloaded files with Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium web driver with chrome to create some test.
The test clicks on a button which causes a zip file to be downloaded to the host.

How can I find the file after downloading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This file will land in the [default download location](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95759?visit_id=1-636224469942357319-1415625026&rd=1#comp_change_default) from Google Chrome
unless set explicitly in your code with `DesiredCapabilities` and `ChromeOptions` as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27834513/4280359).

Default location of Downloads folder.

**nix systems:**

```
String location = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Downloads";
```

**Windows:**

```
String location = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Downloads";
```

Comment: The default location is `System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Downloads"` in *nix systems and `System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Downloads"` in Windows.

Comment: In unix-system to have create the path _/home/<user>/Downloads_ you should use "user.home" system property:
`System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads"`