# how to set chrome download path in protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, end-to-end

how to set chrome download path in protractor?

Is this possible? im about to write e2e tests wherein i need to download a file and set a specific path for it.

here's protractor.conf

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: "chrome",
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ["--disable-gpu"],
        prefs: {
            "download": {
                "prompt_for_download": false,
                "directory_upgrade": true,
                "default_directory": "C:\jobs\\"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The default_folder seems not to be working on my end.

Suggestions and tips are greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: It seems like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824124/how-to-change-file-download-location-in-webdriver-while-using-chrome-driver-fire) shows how to change the download path in Selenium using the Java API. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: hello! i'am using typescript for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already found the fix for it. Here's the updated code

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: "chrome",
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ["--disable-gpu"],
        prefs: {
            download: {
                prompt_for_download: false,
                directory_upgrade: true,
                default_directory: `${__dirname}\\src\\json.file\\`
            }
        }
    }
}
```