# Unable to move the file from C:downloads to other location using selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, automation

I'm downloading one file using selenium now it has been save in path C:Downloads but I want that to save in separate path where I like to save.

Using selenium can I move that desktop file from one location to another where I want or else can I set a path in Eclipse itself where to download the file while executing the script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824124/how-to-change-file-download-location-in-webdriver-while-using-chrome-driver-fire

Comment: @AtulKumarSharma : DesiredCapabilities is deprecated (your solution link)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Java 7** or newer version then you can make use of `Files.move(from, to, CopyOption... options)`

```
Files.move(Paths.get("C:\\Downloads\\Kumar.txt"), Paths.get("Full new file path location"));
```

or else using `Selenium (Options) :`

```
protected static WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void testSO() throws InterruptedException {
  ChromeOptions options =  new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("download.default_directory = C:/Downloads");
  driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
}
```

You can set the value of `download.default_directory` to your desired location.