# Selenium Java - How to set path for download for different systems

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to set the path for download that will work for different systems?
I'm running tests manually and my download path is C:\Users\myUser\Download.

For my colleague the middle folder will be different.
Tests runs with Bamboo on Linux server and path there is different.

Is there a way to set one path that will work everywhere, or a way to check the actual download path and look there?

Can I remove files after download?
I can't manipulate with driver, or chrome options - blocked by framework in company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the path for the system "Downloads" folder:

```
public String downloadPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Downloads\\";
```

Here is to remove the files after download:

```
public boolean isFileDownloaded(String fileName) {
    File dir = new File(downloadPath);
    File[] dirContents = dir.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < dirContents.length; i++) {
        if (dirContents[i].getName().equals(fileName)) {
            dirContents[i].delete();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below link should provide you the answer you need :)
[how to change file download location in Webdriver while using chrome driver/firefox driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824124/how-to-change-file-download-location-in-webdriver-while-using-chrome-driver-fire)

Summary:
In essence you need to add it as a preference in your ChromeOptions

```
String downloadFilepath = "/path/to/download/directory/";
Map<String, Object> preferences = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
preferences.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
preferences.put("download.prompt_for_download", "false");
preferences.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", preferences);
```